# Symbolic Math Toolbox hitting divide by zero error when it used to evaluate to NaN

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I've just updated to Matlab 2014a finally. I have loads of scripts that use the Symbolic Math Toolbox that used to work fine, but now hit the following error:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Division by zero. [_power]
  Evaluating: symobj::trysubs
```

I can't post my actual code here, but here is a simplified example:

```
syms f x y
f = x/y
results = double(subs(f, {'x','y'}, {1:10,-4:5}))
```

In my actual script I'm passing two 23x23 grids of values to a complicated function and I don't know in advance which of these values will result in the divide by zero. Everything I can find on Google just tells me not to attempt an evaluation that will result in the divide by zero. Not helpful! I used to get 'inf' (or 'NaN' - I can't specifically remember) for those it could not evaluate that I could easily filter for when I do the next steps on this data.

Does anyone know how to force Matlab 2014a back to that behaviour rather than throwing the error? Or am I doomed to running an older version of Matlab forever or going through the significant pain of changing my approach to this to avoid the divide by zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a division which has the behaviour you want, this division function returns inf for division by zero:

```
mydiv=@(x,y)x/(dirac(y)+y)+dirac(y)
f = mydiv(x,y)
results = double(subs(f, {'x','y'}, {1:10,-4:5}))
```

Comment: Nice one @Daniel very clever! +1

Comment: A clever workaround. I'm holding out for a solution along the lines of disabling the error though. Since mydiv could not be symbolically manipulated I effectively lose the power of the symbolic toolkit if I have to go that route.